# Novel set in London where a "May" sets up a cleaning company

Tags: identification-request

I'm looking for a novel I read when I was in my teens. All I can remember about it was that part (if not most) of it was set in London.  I think the lead character was called May. She runs out of money and in desperation sets up a cleaning company with two other strangers (young women) who she mets - also in need of money.  One of them lives on a barge and one of them ends up in love with a farmer. I don't think it's particularly high brow.. more chic lit. Possibly written in the 80's or 90's.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think this is very probably *The Rose Revived* by Katie Fforde. This is indeed what could be called "chick-lit", and being published in 1995 fits with the date you remembered.

A [goodreads](https://www.goodreads.com/book/show/12282595-the-rose-revived) summary gives the main points:

> If May, Sally and Harriet didn't need the money so badly, they
> definitely wouldn't be working for Slimeball Slater at Quality
> Cleaners. So when they discover it's Slimeball taking them to the
> cleaners, they decide to set up their own business - and that's when
> things really start to take off.
>
> Working for themselves gives them the freedom and independence they've
> been longing for. May can afford the mooring fees for her beloved
> narrowboat; Harriet discovers a true gift for painting and Sally's
> dream of a place of her own is fast becoming reality. But is it too
> much, having made such a success of their working lives, to expect
> similar success in their romantic ones?

So May is the one who lives on a canal barge. All three of them find love, and it is Sally who meets a young farmer named James Lucas.